# How does a static method use a comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

I have a static method which needs to invoke the `SportsMenComparator`. But this, as we all know is not allowed. How does a static function use a comparator subclass ? Although I have workarounds, I am looking for best practices for this particular problem.

```
final class SportsMan {

    private final String name;
    private final int rank;
    private final String sport;

    public SportsMan (String name, int rank, String sport)  {
        this.name = name;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.sport = sport;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public String getSport() {
        return sport;
    }
}


final class Sport {

    private final String sport;
    private final int numberOfPlayers;

    public Sport(String sport, int numberOfPlayers) {
        this.sport = sport;
        this.numberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayers;
    }

    public String getSport()  {
        return sport;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPlayers() {
        return numberOfPlayers;
    }
}


public final class Joins {

    private Joins () {}



    public class SportsMenComparator implements Comparator<SportsMan> {
        @Override
        public int compare(SportsMan s1, SportsMan s2) {
            return s1.getSport().compareTo(s2.getSport());
        }
     }



    public static void innerJoinSort(List<SportsMan> sportsMans, List<Sport> sportList) {
        Collections.sort(sportsMans, new SportsMenComparator());

    }


}
```

Eclipse results in the following message: `No enclosing instance of type Joins is accessible` where Joins is name of the enclosing class.

Comment: What is the error it is throwing? How are you saying that its not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But this, as we all know is not allowed. How does a static function use a comparator subclass ?

You cannot use a non static `reference`,still you are allowed to create a new object and use it. So since you are creating a new `SportsMenComparator` object and passing, no issues.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> s =new ArrayList<String>();
            s.add(""); // allowed
        }
```

But

```
List<String> s =new ArrayList<String>();
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println();
            s.add(""); // Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field s
        }
```

Edit:

Since you defined the comparator class inside the Joins , you need the Joins object to access the comparation inside it

```
Collections.sort(sportsMans, new Joins().new SportsMenComparator());
```

Answer (score 2):

For using a Comparator, there is no difference between using it from a static- or non-static method. In either case an instance of the Comparator has to be used.

The Garbage Collector of modern JVMs is very efficient at handling short-lived objects. Therefore the penalty to be paid for using a fresh instance (via new) every time is usually no issue. However, if you don't want to use a fresh instance every time, I think the best option would be to add a static field to your SportsMenComparator, containing a singleton instance of the comparator:

```
public class SportsMenComparator implements Comparator<SportsMan> {
  public static final SportsMenComparator instance=new SportsMenComparator();
  @Override
  public int compare(SportsMan s1, SportsMan s2) {
    return s1.getSport().compareTo(s2.getSport());
  }
}

public static void innerJoinSort(List<SportsMan> sportsMans, List<Sport> sportList) {
  Collections.sort(sportsMans, SportsMenComparator.instance);
}
```

Comment: did u mean `public class SportsMenComparator`

Comment: Well, that's what I've written (on line 1). What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to access an instance element (in this case it is a class, indeed the same as with a filed or method) within a static method, which is not associated with an instance. SURESH ATTA's answer is right, but you can also make your `SportsMenComparator` class static and it will work. I do not sse any reason to associate your comparator with an instance of the `Joins` class.

Answer (score 0):

One can use something like this---

```
public static boolean someMethod(MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2){
    return obj1.compare(obj2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you cant include parameter to the function.

```
public static void innerJoinSort(List<SportsMan> sportsMans, List<Sport> sportList, Comparator comparator) {
    Collections.sort(sportsMans, comparator);
}
```

Comment: I can but as said I was not looking for workarounds, but solution to this specific issue